Can a stabilizer tableau with a single row be updated?
The context for this problem is that I wish to know how logical operators evolve over a circuit that is composed of Clifford gates and single qubit measurements. Note that the measurements may be mid-circuit.
I am interested in only a few logical operators such as $X_1$ and not necessarily all of them. I was wondering if the best way to do it is with a tableau that only consists of as many rows as the number of logicals I am interested in tracking.
Explicitly, suppose I have a two qubit state and I know one stabilizer is $X_1$. Can I write down a stabilizer tableau with just one row and update it through a Clifford circuit + single qubit (mid-circuit) measurements to obtain an output tableau that tells me what the state is stabilized by after the circuit? Or do we need to know all the stabilizer generators of the state i.e. $n$ generators for an $n$ qubit state, in order to do the update?
If the above paragraph is possible, does it give us a way to track how a single logical operator evolves through the circuit?

Yes, absolutely. Why not?

I see. I wasn't sure how a logical operator is tracked under measurement. For instance, $\vert 0\rangle$ measured in $X$ basis gives us a random outcome of $\vert +\rangle$ or $\vert -\rangle$. But what is the equivalent statement i.e. when we measure in the $X$ basis, what happens to the $Z$ operator?

Are you wanting to perform measurements mid-circuit, or just at the end?

I want to do mid-circuit measurements too. I will add this to the question to make it clearer

At that point, I'm not even sure exactly what it means to track a single logical operator. If the measurement commutes with your stabilizer, then it's unchanged and you can keep tracking it. If it anti-commutes you can replace that stabilizer with the new measurement operator, but does tracking that tell you what you want about the output? That might depend on what you want to know about the output.

Good points, thanks for the comments!

Yes, you can track partial stabilizer tableaus instead of entire stabilizer tableaus. This can be a useful thing to do when analyzing circuits that involve unknown states or non-stabilizer states propagating through a stabilizer circuit. However, certain operations may no longer be possible (e.g. you won't be able to determine the probability that a measurement should return true unless it's equal to a product of known stabilizers or anticommutes with one of the known stabilizers).
You tagged your question with stim, so I'll just note that stim's tableau class doesn't expose an API for working with partial information. Classes like stim.Tableau and stim.PauliString can be useful for implementing that for yourself, but you'll be doing a lot of the logic for tracking and updating what's known and not known.

So the stabilizer tableau with just a row $X_1\otimes I$ tracks $\vert +\rangle\otimes\vert\psi\rangle$ for any choice of $\psi$ - is that right?
